# Where can I look up total returns of stocks, ETFs, and mutual funds?

Tags: investing, etf, mutual-funds, stock-analysis

I'm looking for a free way to look up total returns of various stocks, ETFs, and mutual funds. [FinanceCharts.com](https://financecharts.com) lets me save lists of stocks and ETFs and view total returns for various time periods, but it doesn't support mutual funds (e.g., FZROX and PIMIX). The free version of Yahoo Finance doesn't seem to offer performance data. Google Finance portfolios doesn't seem to offer performance data at all. Is there a site where I can provide a list of stocks, ETFs, and mutual funds and have it show me total return information for, e.g., 1, 2, 3, and 5 years? I know I can look the information up at Morningstar.com, but, as far as I know, I have to do that separately for each stock/ETF/MF. There does not seem to be a way to create a list of ticker symbols and have performance data for all of them shown at once.

Note that I'm not trying to track the performance of my specific investments. I just want to know the total return that certain stocks, ETFs, and mutual funds have produced over various time periods.

Answer (score 1):

You can view performance of a list of holdings with a free account at seekingalpha.com  I do this regularly, but have not actually tried to automate downloading the information. My list includes stocks, mutual funds, and ETFs.

Comment: This looks promising, but I can't find a way to view the total return for the past year. It's available for the past three years, but for the past year, I see only a way to view "Performance," not "Total Return".  This makes a big difference for income-based investments such as PIMIX. SeekingAlpha's "1Y Perf" is -1.34%, but Morningstar shows 6.62% as its total return for the past year.